pydantic: how know which class was serialized to json
look at example
from pydantic import BaseModel


class A(BaseModel):
    a: float = 0.0


class B(A):
    b: float = 0.0


class C(A):
    c: float = 0.0


b = B(a=1.1, b=2.2)
b_json = b.model_dump_json()

So I have two classes B, C which have a parent A. Here json of B instance is created and then goes somewhere in DB etc. When I take this json in some other time (from DB etc) I need to guess what class it was to correctly parse and deserialize like
B.parse_raw(b_json) # instead C.parse_raw(b_json)

Is there some good practice how to achieve this? Maybe keep some additional information? Or JSON serialization / pydantic not fit well for such purposes ?

JSON doesn't have class information. Maybe use Pickle instead? It's Python-specific and supports classes.

You can use pydantic discriminated unions: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions
(Discriminated Unions with callable Discriminator)

I would say you shouldn't guess what kind of data you took from database. You should make it more explicit by defining methods for getting just A data or B data. For example:
# Models that reflect db schema
@as_declarative(metadata=MetaData(naming_convention=NAMING_CONVENTION))
class BaseOrmModel:
    """Baseclass for custom models."""

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> Any:
        """Declared attribute for building db table name."""

        return ...


class BModel(BaseOrmModel):
    b = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)


class CModel(BaseOrmModel):
    c = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)


# Repository responsible for db queries 
class Repository:
    def get_b(self) -> BModel:
        return select(...)

    def get_c(self): -> CModel:
        return select(...)



# Schemas
class A(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    
    a: float = 0.0


class B(A):
    b: float = 0.0


class C(A):
    c: float = 0.0


# Usage example
repository = Repository()

c_model = repository.get_c()
c_schema = C.model_validate(c_model)

In the example above you are sure that you get B object if you use get_b and can properly map it to B schema.
